# angular2 Dynamic Services in providers

Tags: dynamic, service, angular, provider

i have a simple component like this:

```
import {Service1} from "serv1/sev1";
import {Service2} from "serv2/serv2";
import {Service3} from "serv3/serv3";
import {Component1} from "../........./Component"

   @Component({
     selector: "my-app",
     directives: [Component1, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
     templateUrl: "app.html",
     providers: [Service1,
                 Service2,
                 Service3
              ]
   })
   export class MainComponent {
     constructor(ser1: Service1, ser2: Serivce2, ser3:Service3) {    }
   }

   bootstrap(MainComponent )
```

These services, via DI, will be used as Signleton in various other components of my project.

Now, i Know how to make the "Dynamic component Loader", but I m trying a way to Load, in dynamic way, these services.

So, avoid these "static" Import, read from a JSON file the services name and the services file path, maybe put them in an array, put this array inside the "providers", all of this at bootstrap time.

What do you think ?

Comment: Any concrete use case?

Comment: What do you exactly try to implement? I mean why do you need dynamic services and how do you want to it within the component?

Comment: Now i just use these 3 services; if i want to Inject some other services in my components.. i have to change the component in the example, i have to add the new import and the new entry in the "providers".But, with a dynamic loader, i ll have just to modify the JSON file with the services name and the services file path